# Create a Language of The Month answer scraper

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

When I was posting answers for the [Husk Language of The Month thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19387/80214), I realized it took more time to enter them in the thread than it took to actually write the answers. So, why not automate it?

Write a program/function which inputs a language name, and displays all answers in that language during the current month so far)

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20474/80214)

## Introduction

You are to find all answers in Code Golf Stack Exchange in the current month so far, whose first non-empty line matches the following:

```
#<whitespace>[<language name>(case insensitive match)]<anything else>
```

For example, the current month's answers should have been posted within the time frame of Nov 1 till the current date(Nov 6, as of this question's sandbox post).

for each answer, you must find the following:

- Question name
- Answer URL
- Answer Poster's Name
- Answer Poster's Profile URL

And format them in the following manner for Markdown:

```
- [<Question Name>](Answer URL) by [<Answer Poster's Name>]
```

Once you are done listing the answers, to keep the post short, you must key in the usernames to their respective profile URLs as follows:

```
- [<Answer Poster's Name>]:<Answer Poster's Profile URL>
```

This must be added at the end of the output.

## Output

The final result should look like the following:

```
- [Size up a number](http://example1.com) by [Razetime]
- [My smartphone's Phonebook](http://example2.com) by [Bubbler]
- [1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz](http://example3.com) by [Lyxal]
- [Upgoat or Downgoat?](http://example3.com) by [LegionMammal978]
- .....

[Razetime]:http://exampleA.com
[Bubbler]:http://exampleB.com
[Lyxal]:http://exampleC.com
[LegionMammal978]:http://exampleD.com
...
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Does it have to work for any current month or just '21 Feb?

Comment: It has to work for any month.

Comment: But we get only the language name as input? So it works only for a concrete month?

Comment: It works on the current month so far, with the language name as input. If you want, I'll also add that as an optional input.

Comment: @Razetime is [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=husk+is%3Aanswer+created%3A1m) something like what you're looking for?

Comment: no, till  the current date. Eg(for this month): 2020-02-01 - 2020-02-9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>283</s> 282 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žgŽ7?-©ƵÇ+400÷®<т÷(®69-4÷®70-365*•ΘÏF•ºS₂+žf<£`žgт‰0Kθ4ÖOŽª+·*’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/–«?€¼=ƒËŠˆ&€š‚‚=ÿ’žYì.w„†ä_¡¦ε',¡нþ}Ùε’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/’žYì©’ÿ…é/ÿ’.w……<h1¡¦ε„><S¡3èy’="/a/’¡1è'"¡н®"ÿa/ÿ"y'†§™’ÜÇ.µÔ/ÿ’¡1è…><"S¡64Sè`®¨ì)}ćнδª}€`ʒнlIlQ}ʒ1è'/¡4èXså]DεƵ=Sè`“- [ÿ](ÿ)€‹ [ÿ]“}»sε32Sè`"[ÿ]:ÿ"}Ù»¶2×ý
```

Ugh..

No TIO of the full program, because `.w` is disabled.

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Get the current year and month, and convert it to a Unix timestamp (using [this formula](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16)):

```python
žg                     # Push the current year
  Ž7?-                 # Subtract 1900
      ©                # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
       ƵÇ+             # Add 299
          400÷         # Integer-divide by 400
      ®                # Push year-1900 again from variable `®`
       <               # Subtract 1
        т÷             # Integer-divide by 100
          (            # Negate it
      ®                # Push year-1900 again
       69-             # Subtract 69
          D            # Duplicate it
           4÷          # Integer-divide the copy by 4
          s            # Swap so year-1969 is at the top again
           <           # Subtract 1 to make it year-1970
            365*       # Multiply by 365
•ΘÏF•                  # Push compressed integer 5254545
     º                 # Mirror it to 52545455454525
      S                # Convert it to a list of digits
       ₂+              # Add 26 to each: [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31,28,31]
         žf            # Push the current month
           <           # Subtract it by 1
            £          # Leave that many trailing items in the list
             `         # Pop and push them all separated to the stack
žg                     # Push the current year again
  т‰                   # Divmod by 100: [year//100,year%100]
    0K                 # Remove 0s from this pair
      θ                # Leave the last item
       4Ö              # Check if it's divisible by 4
                       # (this results in 1 for leap years; 0 for non-leap years)
O                      # Sum all values on the stack
 Žª+                   # Push compressed integer 43200
    ·                  # Double it to 86400
     *                 # Multiply the sum by this 86400
```

[Try just this first step online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70o3vN7XUPrTy29XC7tomBweHth9bZXGw6vF3j0DozS10TEN/cQNfYzFTrUcOiczMO97sB6UO7gh81NWkf3Zdmc2hxAtCUi02PGjYYeJ/bYXJ4mv/RvYdWaR/arvX/PwA)

Step 2: Use this timestamp to create the stackexchange-API URL, and get the content of this url (which contains the JSON of all answers created this month):

```python
’¸¸.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/–«?€¼=ƒËŠˆ&€š‚‚=ÿ’
                       # Push dictionary string "api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=codegolf&fromdate=ÿ",
                       # where the `ÿ` is automatically replaced with the timestamp
 žYì                   # Prepend constant "https://"
    .w                 # Browse to this URL, and read its contents as string
```

[Try the first two steps online (without `.w`).](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70o3vN7XUPrTy29XC7tomBweHth9bZXGw6vF3j0DozS10TEN/cQNfYzFTrUcOiczMO97sB6UO7gh81NWkf3Zdmc2hxAtCUi02PGjYYeJ/bYXJ4mv/RvYdWaR/aDtQw89COQzv0DgMlZz1q2Hlol97RSUcn6T9qmHxotf2jpjWH9tgem3S4@@iC021qQO7RhWB1s2wP7wdqPbov8vCa//8B)

Step 3: Extract all unique answer-id and question-ids from this JSON:

```python
D                      # Duplicate the JSON
 „†ä_¡                 # Split it on dictionary string "question_"
      s                # Swap so the JSON is at the top again
       „Ž»_¡           # Split it on dictionary string "answer_"
            ‚          # Pair those two lists together
ε                      # Map over the pairs:
 ¦                     #  Remove the first item
  ε                    #  Map over each inner string:
   ',¡                '#   Split it on ","
      н                #   Pop and leave just the first item
       þ               #   Pop and leave just the digits in this string
  }Ù                   #  After the inner map: uniquify the resulting ids
}                      # Close the outer map
```

[Try just this third step with the JSON as input.](https://tio.run/##7ZrbbtvIGYBfxeBFemOZcz4YCArFieNgk8BOgt0kRSGMyKFEhyIVkvIpCJDXaC@KXWDRN9irYnuRoLeLPkNeJJ0huakskrJMM72pDRuQ9Wt@zvDTf2aSqXGov3y5//nD3z5/@PHTz6OPP2Xm9b9@/fgP8/Lzh7/@9svHv//2yx@2P/70718//fP9p7@8//LFcZx3TpjrWebs/umdk5zGOnV23zmpni9ylYdJ7OxiJLnYdhaZTkeh7@wyAhGs/s/P59rZNR@fhFmuU@072848TYIw0qNwpiZWOM3zebbruqenpzuTVJ2oXKU7XjJzy5cuQZRBJEUw9nxAfeEpphVDeqwUAcz3/5jdhUjc8e@Gvo7z0EviO@ndw4d3grvQXM0Ps3mkzkexmtmLJSeZeTMK4zdLV/YSX0@SKNjJcuW90WfeVMUTXezBniJziyO5du37bSfMRsrz9Dw3p9kNVJTpbSfzktSoB0a1ynIjz8OTMD8f@So3b0OzfyEApaiSaz/MG2Reqot7elmEiNx2VJydVvcXQfMm23beLnRWfPrrm9SoSOLc3IVRFHo6zuyJ9/a27r0aPB9ukR1gtt8CUTAB5BJEihAEayCWd2CUFhuVrJ1qWN7UnXA2WZRYn@jg@eHO8XxSgZs0cfpOn4Tx1l66CI@zTMcdmBUncN9YPQPvq571/OBafkSAVn6FrIEf5@YXr/LjtIEfY7g7P87gEj0IALaX6M0GGZQSc0oB9pAPAq09OQbcpxqLMeUBv5YN3lcn5mMdkJbHcv1y/XqUaA1KziFuQ1nJmkwRU0BIDaUkdZSGeneUEi4bIqPS2vW1Sdbtbu/0bf7yKrt7kIbe1v3FLIzDqIujtLt1tVEy8CslN8DEjGW1YSplTZg44ZDUPWbfmBATYNlhUmy19cBpSNP986s4zdVxYtB0cIt2n261fD0bvI4N5Ri3sSllTWwYkUjU2eCe2VDGl9BICS39HtDER2hxehWa@yoOuyQZxTaNc7Orb2A0hBHWBqaUNYGBkNp4v@LbOOsZDKQM0yU0xNiq6DFOmeQQA02CMfM9qscyCChQATSmyjVDQLfEqTrEPJt2QFgcx7Vr1wMkawECTFoBFrImgFRShuqWBXoHSARZAmjSU9jFtqIp2ZkkySTSdmm1m@JODh6@uBiMZKZf@sIdfv159N/Xbx@4FxLvATw48Z5k7nya5ElplBeWbh3mM3Wh83DWJeUozuemvytYj5Wuwwokh21YS1kDViYIFfX00WYEK1g5k@AGWAngBC2HM0FtOrpZ/i/odZzoQRjsH1zlRIdprBaR3yXA2Z27qlrfPcIxZuraFmCVrNGREo5Y3ZGKnu3wtujeyJkyilhbmlLJmiAiAGmt6OYC9e1M4UrRVthwbwwDxgBVZpOI@AJDiE2xRnCgAkA8MpbgWgz12TzVWXacQYS7lW7mcO4lLd17KcycpS3DLEWrcRCuogOM2TqrKzom2XIaQxEC/UbB6eAhPwolVjppjoL3PffAP5ul6dGBIkcbRMHnx4lO/UMdx2E86WKQxSndrFAz/11Nd4hUckJbbLOSNSc6mNJ6FS5XANuvO7tJniP5cnnHpKB92ubYN85UBL5xsGPM1djjGiksfYQFMrXq9RoqdlcIII5kFzdrT@YuqegeMqnZe5u3rWRNOY4EsKH2AKJforcdzqvxQSZbjK4UrRpd31kNQnwZkSlpOOylcM/fvnm2vzOPryzcdbR1sNOleLdbLYp3HQ2mN2gzm3wftvUmK1kTIAIEafCKvA4I2frttvz7BuXfWqxQwrZqopI1TQ8gKbq/K1hRPZuRAN2g/JMMXAp2CMuNiz9O12FmbZifjx8//06pF8P4tBnz/tDVk6NH8@OHBGViA8yPddIl/NmzupFZ273nZowPkla7hA0zA9YzQAjQcikhOZOwX7NU@vwALvbTJ2kLr@HQHT55vVh48Q/34PEB9EZD8MOeH76@mCee/zTkg8PpJmnq0GY8pIsLtod2Vbm8e1pKAMSsDWYhWoVZa8aYfIbe@tj/uY/FErbOJCpZk49lBDR0bOhqsQ8BLsa2t1i/AVa8FitgqBVrIWvCSjHj9aqCiJ6N1WCly1ghZwBtGjuty792Z45i4Y2lr4mERJkvqg@xryjwuEcAU9frzD3Vnca8xSHdWF853l3L1eCALZP2UrTqaPseE0JGl9MeScDatKdDloNydhZFh2h@b9hskacTdxofTV9P9o6Rv0l4fKCyc5Udhl0CpD2fqwsF87CNnPn8bBFbVvae@Zd62ybA0o0yIgwpbLXZUtbYPC8vsNp3XU13CSlm712xEztyWeLOTQYOeikzH7/@/tXRVWXmvcV4HJldXR9gsVF3XK2/QaAEFLXNoipZAx0KjVet5bIMN3TFKb9JoEQYoUtmKfqcbFACRUA5V@NAcY8i6fsm/nOECUNjQsDGI@KnSeJHWnYyRAHduFrevezAAAjSirGQNRmZSWJtubk6oWqaFN/kiTRECLr0FEbxwE5vGAGTlEs@ZoBhSHAQcKkDTZUUihPM4MYYVaTnUxWZvy4kzaHcJQ3dyw4khWx5oKkSrUbDvu3uFtg1gVHQCqwQrQKrdW0gEzeJYxJAcqlbChHrJYy9evRy/@zKx5wS@3yft3Wi4q0HHTvYxZZdv9Q0MJoGeoMeNltLBdouf6NPrGSNxLCk9RpQkN4HvstpB@WU9ptuRt@zQfTs/MXhWUu6ee/IvXiciRf85UDnrzZIN/d1FGaHU5XNulhbcUQ3sDrmpY7uSQsqOy3NZEtZI1kiecMoX9YfoKGY39aB36gOXA@26D43witFq46071Tl/9WRrqXCKWw1t1LWYm4U1c2tNssFoiwCryD2523H@I3RrNhuni601ZPkajRTZ84uLh9vtP@neqZC@0SCuaAg7x3H@Q8)

Step 4: Convert each question-id to an URL, and get its contents (which is the entire HTML page of a question):

```python
`                      # Pop and push both lists separated to the stack
 U                     # Pop the list of answer-ids and store it in variable `X`
ε                      # Map over the question-ids:
 ’ƒËŠˆ.Â‚‹º.ŒŒ/’       #  Push dictionary string "codegolf.stackexchange.com/"
   žYì                 #  Prepend constant "https://"
      ©                #  Store this string in variable `®` (without popping)
       ’ÿ…é/ÿ’         #  Push dictionary string "ÿ/questions/ÿ",
                       #  where the first `ÿ` is automatically replaced with "https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/"
                       #  and the second `ÿ` is automatically replaced with the current question-id
              .w       #  Browse to this URL, and read its contents as string
```

[Try steps 3 and 4 with JSON input (without `.w`)](https://tio.run/##7ZpNb9vIGYD/isFDerHE@R6OgaCQnTgONgnsON2NUxTqiBxKdChSISl/BQGMHnrpLbf0UOwCxQIL9JpDW@wWsJFeCgT9Df4j6fBjU1kkZZlmeqkNG6b1cl7O8PH7ORPGcuCpT5/uXZz@6eL02/M/98@@i/X1hx/P/q4vL07/@PH92fcf3/9i9ey7f/94/tOb83dvfvurj@8vTt/98@35Hz58@6/fd89/p2@7OP3r2d@6H95@eGtq2Yef9s7/cvaDvjr/x8Xp9@c/mOnvd58@GYbx2vASNY6NtV@/NsLDQEXG2msjUpNpIhMvDIw1jAS3Vo1prKK@5xhrjEAEi7@T44ky1vTtQy9OVKQcY9WYRKHr@arvjeUwFY6SZBKvmebh4WF3GMkDmcioa4djM780CaIMImG5A9sB1LFsyZRkSA2kJIA5zi/juxBZd5y7nqOCxLPD4E50d/vBHfcu1E9zvHjiy@N@IMfpw8KDWH/oe8HLmSfboaOGoe9240TaL9WRPZLBUGVzSFcRm9mSzHTsm1XDi/vSttUk0atZc6Ufq1UjtsNIqwdatYwTLU@8Ay857jsy0R9DPX/LApSiQq4cL6mQ2ZHK3ullESJi1ZBBfFi8XwT1h2zVeDVVcXb35w@pVhEGiX4Lfd@zVRCnK97YWFnf6@z2VkgX6OnXQLSYBcQMRIoQBAsg5m@gH2UTFayeqpe/1K43Hk5zrI@Vu7vd3Z8MC3DDKk5fqQMvWNmIpt5@HKugAbNsBebLVE/H/qxnMT@4kB@xQC2/TFbBj3P9jef5cVrBjzHcnB9ncIYeBACnj2jNBhkUAnNKAbaRA1ylbDEA3KEKWwPKXX4tG7wnD/RtDZDmyzKdfPxilGgBSs4hrkNZyKpMEVNASAmlIGWUmnpzlALOGiKjIrXra5Ms293G4avk@VV2dz/y7JV707EXeH4TR5nO1lRaSccplNwAE9OWVYcpl1Vh4oRDUvaYbWNCzAKzDpPiVFsLnHo02jy@itNE7ocaTQO3mM7TLIYvZoMXsaEc4zo2uayKDSMCWWU2uGU2lPEZNELAlH4LaIIdND28Cs09GXhNkoxsmtq5paNvYDSEEVYHJpdVgYGQpvF@zrdx1jIYSBmmM2iItlWrxTilk0MMFHEHzLGpGgjXpUC6UJsqVwwBVROnyhCTeNQAYbYcMx27GCBZCBBgUgswk1UBpIIyVLYs0DpAYpEZgDo9hU1syx@R7jAMh75Khxazyd5k58Gzk05fxOq5Y5m9z18P/3v96r55IvAGwJ0D@3FsTkZhEuZGeZLSLcN8Kk9U4o2bpBzZ@szoZwWLsdJFWIHgsA5rLqvAyixCrXL6mGYEc1g5E@AGWAngBM2GM4um6ehy@b9Fr@NEtzx3c@sqJ9qLAjn1nSYBLp25KYvxzSMcY7qurQFWyCodKeGIlR2p1bId3hbdSzlTRhGrS1MKWRVEBCAtFd3cQm07UzhXtGU23BpDlzFApZ4kIo6FIcS6WCPYlS4gNhkIcC2G6mgSqTjejyHCzUo3vTjzkpbmvRSm11KXYeai@TgI59EBxtI6qyk6JthsGkMRAu1GwVHnAd/xBJYqrI6C92xzyzkaR9HOliQ7S0TB3f1QRc62CgIvGDYxyGyVZpypmfyspjlEKjihNbZZyKoTHUxpuQoXc4DTf3d2kzxH8NnyjgmLtmmbA0c7U8t1tIMdYC4HNldIYuEgbCFdq16voZLOCgHEkWjiZtOVmTMqmodMqude520LWVWOIwCsqD2A1S7R2w7n1fggEzVGl4vmja7trAYhPotIlzQctlK4J69ePt3sToIrC3flr2x1mxTv6VSz4l35ndEN2sw634d1vclCVgWIAItUeEVeBoTS@u22/PsC5d9CrFDAumqikFXtHkCSdX/nsKJyNiMAukH5Jxi4FOwQFksXf5wuwszqMO8OHu1@JeWzXnBYjXmzZ6rhzsPJ/gOCYmsJzI9U2CT8pWs1fT22ec9NGx8ktXYJK/YMWMsAIUCzpYTgTMB2zVKq4y043YweRzW8ej2z9/jFdGoH36zD/S1o93vgmw3He3EyCW3nicc726Nl0tRemvGQJi44XbQp8@HN01ICIGZ1MDPRPMxSM0bnM/TWx/7PfSwWsHZPopBV@VhGQEXHhs4X@xDgbNv2FusXwIoXYgUM1WLNZFVYKWa8XFUQq2Vj1VjpLFbIGUDLxs7U5V@7M0exZQ@Eo4iAROp/VAdiR1Jgc5sAJq/XmXuiGm3zZos0A3Xl9u5CrhoHrNlpz0XzjrbtbULI6GzaIwhYmPY0yHJQwo58fxtN1nvVFnk4NEfBzujFcGMfOcuEx/syPpbxttckQKbrM1WmYOLVkdP3j6dByip9Z86l3rYOsHSpjAhDCmttNpdVNs/zB8z3XefTXUKyvfem2Em65TLDnesMHLRSZj568fXezlVl5vp0MPD1rK4PMJuoOSjG3yBQAorq9qIKWQUdCrVXLeWyDFd0xSm/SaBEGKFLZmm1ubNBCbRcyrkcuJLbFAnH0fGfI0wYGhAClt4ifhKGjq9EI0O0oBkUw5uXHRgAi9RizGRVRqaT2LTcnN@hqtopvsmJNEQIunQKIzuw0xpGwATlgg8YYBgS7LpcKFdRKSzJCWZwaYzSV5OR9PVPE5J6UeaMhuZlBxKWqDnQVIjmo2HbdncL7JrAKKgFlonmgZW6NpBZN4ljAkByqVsKEWsljO09fL55dOUxpzA932evHMhg5X7DDnY2ZdPJNXW0po5aoofNFlKBaZe/0icWskpiWNByDWiR1jd8Z9MOyiltN930v2Yd/@nxs@2jmnRzfcc8eRRbz/jzjkr2lkg3N5XvxdsjGY@bWFu2RNNNdUxyHc2TFpR3WqrJ5rJKskTwiq18UT5AQzG/rQO/UB24GGzWfa6El4vmHWnbqcr/qyNdSIVTWGtuuazG3Cgqm1tpLxdYeRF4BbHfrBrab/TH2XSTaKpSPWEi@2N5ZKzh/Hhj@nekxtJLTyToB1rkjWEY/wE).

Step 5: For each HTML-content of a question, get a list of its `[language_name, answer_url, user_name, user_url, question_name]` (this may contain some garbage in the result - i.e. the trailing item, or if an answer contains multiple `<h1>`-refs, but we'll filter those out later):

```python
…<h1¡                  #  Split the HTML-content on "<h1"
     ¦                 #  Remove the first item
      ε                #  Map over each string:
       „><S¡           #   Split it on both ">" and "<"
            3è         #   Get the fourth item (which is the question name in the first iteration,
                       #   and language name in every other iteration)
       y               #   Push the string again
        ’="/a/’¡      "#   Split it on "="/a/"
                1è     #   Get the second item (which is the trailing answer-id URL portion)
                  '"¡ '#   Split that on '"'
                     н #   Pop and leave the first item
        ®              #   Push "https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/" from variable `®`
         "ÿa/ÿ"        #   Push dictionary string "ÿa/ÿ",
                       #   where the `ÿ` are filled again to create the answer-URL
       y               #   Push the string again
        '†§           '#   Push dictionary string "person"
           ™           #   Titlecase it to "Person"
            ’ÜÇ.µÔ/ÿ’  #   Push dictionary string "schema.org/ÿ",
                       #   where the `ÿ` is replaced with "Person"
             ¡         #   Split the string on that
              1è       #   Get the second item
        …><"S¡        "#   Split that on ">", "<", and '"'
              64Sè     #   Get the seventh and fifth items
                       #   (which are the user name and trailing user URL portion)
                  `    #   Push those separated to the stack
                   ®   #   Push "https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/" again
                    ¨  #   Remove the trailing "/"
                     ì #   Prepend it in front to create the user-URL
       )               #   Wrap all four values into a list
      }ć               #  After the map: extract the first quadruple
        н              #  Pop and push its first item (the question name)
         δ             #  Map over each remaining quadruples
          ª            #   And append the question name as trailing item to each
```

[Try just this fifth step with the HTML as input.](https://pastebin.com/AKC8p6Fc)

Step 6: Filter this list, so it only contains answers from the earlier list, and only the language that's equal to the input:

```python
ʒ                      #  Filter this list of quintuples by:
 н                     #   Pop and leave its first item (the language name)
  l                    #   Convert it to lowercase
   Il                  #   Get the input in lowercase as well
     Q                 #   And check that both are equal
}ʒ                     #  After the filter: filter once again:
  1è                   #   Get the second item (the answer URL)
    '/¡               '#   Split it on "/"
       4è              #   Leave its fifth item (the answer-id)
         X             #   Push the list of answer-ids from variable `X`
          så           #   And check if the current answer-id is in it
]                      # Close both the filter and outer map
```

[Try just the sixth step with the list of quintuples of the previous step as input.](https://tio.run/##rZZPTtwwFMb3nMLKpiAx4/xPXAEVUKRCJdSCKlUaZmESMzGTsaPYiWDRS3CDLipxiW7KjlVvNPXAxM4qHUvMYvRkv@/zL/Hzc7jA15Qsvy2fH/7@Lk/Lrz@eH7ynx3fwz8/w6fG7ePo1XS4nTuCjJHV2geN7aerG6yiJdIRCPWuioJtNYj3mdmNupGc75yT1dZ6nnZFW6DxkoqSLfKMwVHqNqHNOQqPVfGmnjQOdl2hSpMeQXiMNdaT5kFakqTPdmkycT42Yr8YKKSvxHsKM52TGy5uxkDibk7uswGxGxhlfQAxfbWHk@96L0Ue@oIxmoMUMnAhB2IZOjSC1gCjy/Bjmrx4j5TEincepAFQCrIwXFa0JYM3imtQfnOkumDhndryu4T3jDBdWjF4UxgjedrpBri/3suAM@HZ4vsHjrbCCi0PP9@BaNYh2xTaGOjjDLb7MalpJsH1yGe/sAhSA63tJxB4svIMrtlcdHArRLIgAssBS/RFAWdVIUGABVCmQlrD1@oDfgJzOqBRjcEFkUzOVAY44L4lKbHHZkPEerJTryldhZyUWYn9FC6vNmKu3fPrXw2625LBmuClzq22J0igOIDbK4Wruve5zZT2@FTs2uKpfGVwp7Mo7DBMvhWvVIOZxgeuM49LqTaLAoJ0TWtodvSR2fcjWskE4Nzo88k7s0Hqb/Jm0lIHjuqG31k3sxQTOVw6jrO8wvOmkLO/t@kRseO/ojFO7VpuiKIJa9/ZtLOnhfcSM2jUyhDw3hHmnGy5EsD3Lsh27ze7fWbilObGrRNcNInVTaeUg4IXd6e0dkQqri2ZuV35RkPjQCP/TB0HvtzFmrycDqb7FWE7u9jdTgxxLPJK4nhG5P8g33Vp9ifwD)

Step 7: Convert it to the output in the specified format:

```python
 €`                    # After the map over the questions, flatten it one level down
   D                   # Duplicate this list
    ε                  # Map over the quintuplets:
     Ƶ=                #  Push compressed integer 214
       Sè              #  Leave just the third, second, and fifth items
          `            #  Pop and push them separated to the stack
      “- [ÿ](ÿ)€‹ [ÿ]“ #  Push dictionary string "- [ÿ](ÿ) by [ÿ]",
                       #  where the `ÿ` are filled again
    }»                 # After the map: join the strings by newlines
   sε                  # Swap, and map over the quintuplets again:
     32Sè              #  Leave just the fourth and third items
         `             #  Pop and push them separated to the stack
      "[ÿ]:ÿ"          #  Push string "[ÿ]:ÿ",
                       #  where the `ÿ` are filled again
    }»                 # After the map: join the strings by newlines as well
      ¶2×ý             # Then join these two strings with "\n\n" as delimiter
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[Try just the sixth and seventh steps with the list of quintuplets of step five as input.](https://tio.run/##rZZNa9swGMfv/RTClzXQRH5/KU1H32DtoGwtg0EamGqrsVpHNpYc2kOh7CP0Mga77DDoYdcORimFGHbooewz9ItkThvLPnkRNIegPHr@f/1iPXrkmKFDgicfJveXf2@j7ej9@f2lll@9guPvZn71keU/@psP13@uu/v51afHi29t0Mvv@ov5Xevx88/Hi99PP4v4@fiGPVwb@jRNmcaW8zvlPP86vhn/0vMv@e1k0lMM3XNcZQkouua6qj0bOZYYeaaYrUZGOevYIqaWMdUSs6Wz4@oiTxPOnlCIPK8aOeVIrxQVlVjDKp0ds9IKPrfU2obIcwSpJ2KeWMM1xUjweULhukp/oddT3mTsZBoLOU/YMoR@HOBBHB11GEf@CT71Q0QHuOPHQ4jgsy20dF17MtqMh4QSH4wQBVuMYTqnU8ZwyqBnaboNg2ePduHRxqXHNgOEA1QYDxOSYkCz4SFOXyv9JdBTduR41Yp3J6YolGLULNP24HGpa@R6d8bDmAJdDk@v8OIRk4KzTU3X4EzViHZA54Za3UEjtO@nJOFgcWvfbi0BzwCHZxyzFRhqqwd0JVldYywbYgZ4iHjxhQGhScZBiBgoSgGPMJ2tD@IjEJAB4awD9jDPUlpkgPU4jnCROEJRhjsrMClcp74Fth8hxrpTWpjMx5y85L9/PuzVlqylFGVRILUtlmvZBkSVsrmaa497t7DuHLOWDG7RrypczuTK2zQdzYUzVSPmRohSP0aR1JP0jAptF5NI7ug5tqpDOpM1wqnW2rq2JYdW2@S3eEQo2EgzcizdxJ5M4MnUoe3XHZo3HUfRmVyfsCveUzKIiVyrdT3LgkL38m3MqeFtIkrkGpnnaaoJg1LXXIhgceD7LbnNrt9ZaEQCLFeJqmpYxU0llI2Ae3Knt3ZEElRcNCdy5WcZjg4r4X/6IKh95sas9WTAizc6GuDT7nxqECCO2hylA8y7jXz9hembyD8)

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the dictionary strings and compressed integers work.

Comment: When you get an 05AB1E answer as long as this one, it's a sign that either the question is too tricky, or the answerer has too much time on their hands. When it's the only answer, though - Nice job!

Comment: @Ausername Haha. Probably both tbh. ;)

Comment: +1, first 05AB1E answer > 200 bytes.

Comment: Also, sweet explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.6 and later + BeautifulSoup + requests, 681 bytes

```
from bs4 import*
from requests import*
from datetime import datetime as d
import json
def l(b):
 c='https://';s='.stackexchange.com';z="";y="";a=json.loads(get(c+'api'+s+'/answers?site=codegolf&fromdate='+d(d.now().year,d.now().month,1).strftime('%s')).text)
 for x in a['items']:
  k=BeautifulSoup(get(f"{c}codegolf{s}/questions/{x['question_id']}#{x['answer_id']}").text);t=k.select(f"#answer-{x['answer_id']}>div>div.answercell.post-layout--right>div.s-prose.js-post-body>h1");q=k.select('.question-hyperlink')[0];n=x['owner']['display_name']
  if t and b in t[0].text:z+=f"- [{q.text}]({c+'codegolf'+s+q['href']}) by [{n}]\n";y+=f"[{n}]:{x['owner']['link']}\n"
 print(z+"\n"+y)
```

Relevant function is `l`, where you pass the name of language `b`

Explanation coming soon